# Why do I need to specify an xml namespace when I do serialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, serialization

I do not quite understand the reason why I need to specify an xml namespace for an object when I serialize the object to the wire. By default, the xml namespace for this object will be the CLR namespace of this object, this is enough for us to differentiate two objects with the same Class name, but within different namespace. So what's the point that the `ContractNamespaceAttribute` or `DataContractAttribute.Namespace` even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the xml namespace for this object will be the CLR namespace of this object

Is not great for interoperability with other software. The default is considered a develop-time stub. When you develop a separate Client and Server, only one could rely on this default.

It is a best practice to select a meaningful namespace.